NavigationLink inside nested List only triggers the outer List row when clicked and doesn't navigate properly
I want to have a list of tasks and each task have a list of navigationLinks each NavigationLink has subtaskName as a label and subtaskDetails as destination and every list (tasks list and subtasks list) has .onDelete and .onMove behaviors
But when I implement the code below the navigation link act weird. navigationLink inside List inside List is not navigating when clicked and it is only triggered and navigates to SubtaskDetailView when clicking the outer List row. How can I fix this problem?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tasks: [Task] = [
        Task(name: "Task 1", subtasks: [
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 1", details: "Details for Subtask 1"),
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 2", details: "Details for Subtask 2")
        ]),
        Task(name: "Task 2", subtasks: [
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 1", details: "Details for Subtask 1"),
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 2", details: "Details for Subtask 2")
        ]),
        Task(name: "Task 3", subtasks: [
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 1", details: "Details for Subtask 1"),
            Subtask(name: "Subtask 2", details: "Details for Subtask 2")
        ])
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(tasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TaskView(task: $tasks[index])
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
                .onMove(perform: moveTask)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Tasks")
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteTask(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    private func moveTask(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        tasks.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}

struct TaskView: View {
    @Binding var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(task.name)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.bottom, 4)
            ForEach(task.subtasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: SubtaskDetailView(details: task.subtasks[index].details)) {
                    Text(task.subtasks[index].name)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                task.subtasks.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            })
            .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                task.subtasks.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
            })
        }
        .frame(minHeight: CGFloat(task.subtasks.count) * 80)
    }
}

struct SubtaskDetailView: View {
    let details: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(details)
            .navigationTitle("Subtask Details")
    }
}

struct Task: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var subtasks: [Subtask]
}

struct Subtask: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var details: String
}


You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”, and search for the Navigation Migration Guide.

IMO one list where Task = Section, and Subtask = list item would be much better, and solves your problem too

Using indices in SwiftUI loops as a source of identify is problematic, especially with onMove and .onDelete.  You need to reference the identifiable data directly.

@timbretimbre if I made Task = Section can I implement .onMove and .onDelete on the sections ?

ForEach is not a for loop you shouldn't use it with indices and it'll crash attempting that array[x] subscript if the data changes, use it like this instead:
ForEach($tasks) { $task in
    TaskView(task: $task)
}

When you use structs for model data and have a one-to-many relationship you need to flatten the data structure and use ids, you can't use an array of the sub-entity like you can with objects because you're always working with copies. You can find an example of this in Apple's Fruta sample for the favourite smoothies.
NavigationView has many issues so it's best to use the new NavigationStack (and .navigationDestination/NavigationPath) or NavigationSplitView.
